# The view function did not return a valid response. Flask-marshmallow, RestAPI

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I write application on `Flask`. For `RestAPI` I'm use `flask-marshmallow`. But I get error.

> The view function did not return a valid response. The return type must be a string, dict, tuple, Response instance, or WSGI callable, but it was a list.
>   I do everything as in the example
>   https://flask-marshmallow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
class ApplicationSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        fields = ("id", "name")

applications_schema = ApplicationSchema(many=True)

@bp.route("")
def applications():
    all_applications = Application.query.all()
    return applications_schema.dump(all_applications)
```

Comment: There is a similar complaint here: https://github.com/jmcarp/flask-apispec/issues/160 ... I think it's an incompatibility in the latest version(s) of Flask. Perhaps Flask used to accept a list as output, but it no longer does?

Comment: change `dump` to `dumps` :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to correct this by placing the return inside of jsonify.  You can import it from flask and it'll look like this:

```
from flask import jsonify

@bp.route("")
    def applications():
        all_applications = Application.query.all()
        return jsonify(applications_schema.dump(all_applications))
```